# sed parsing xml file1 index file2

Tags: xml, file, parsing, sed

I need one liner that will match line in **`file1`**   `/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http:/someurl` based on weather code `(/data/weather/weatherCode=116)` get correct **url** from **`file2`**

#### FILE1

```
/data/weather/date=2011-12-18
/data/weather/tempMaxC=25
/data/weather/tempMaxF=76
/data/weather/tempMinC=14
/data/weather/tempMinF=56
/data/weather/windspeedMiles=15
/data/weather/windspeedKmph=24
/data/weather/winddirection=NE
/data/weather/winddir16Point=NE
/data/weather/winddirDegree=39
/data/weather/weatherCode=112
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http:/someurl
/data/weather/weatherDesc= Cloudy 
/data/weather/precipMM=0.0
/data/weather
/data/weather/date=2011-12-19
/data/weather/tempMaxC=29
/data/weather/tempMaxF=84
/data/weather/tempMinC=17
/data/weather/tempMinF=63
/data/weather/windspeedMiles=13
/data/weather/windspeedKmph=21
/data/weather/winddirection=N
/data/weather/winddir16Point=N
/data/weather/winddirDegree=360
/data/weather/weatherCode=116
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http://someurl
/data/weather/weatherDesc=Partly Cloudy 
/data/weather/precipMM=14.1
```

#### FILE 2

```
/data/weather/weatherCode=111
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon1.png
/data/weather/weatherCode=112
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon2.png
/data/weather/weatherCode=113
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon3.png

----------
/data/weather/weatherCode=120
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon20.png
```

#### Desired Result (File1 should get edited)

**FILE1(edited)**

```
    /data/weather/date=2011-12-18
    /data/weather/tempMaxC=25
    /data/weather/tempMaxF=76
    /data/weather/tempMinC=14
    /data/weather/tempMinF=56
    /data/weather/windspeedMiles=15
    /data/weather/windspeedKmph=24
    /data/weather/winddirection=NE
    /data/weather/winddir16Point=NE
    /data/weather/winddirDegree=39
    /data/weather/weatherCode=112
    /data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon12.png
    /data/weather/weatherDesc= Cloudy 
    /data/weather/precipMM=0.0
    /data/weather
    /data/weather/date=2011-12-19
    /data/weather/tempMaxC=29
    /data/weather/tempMaxF=84
    /data/weather/tempMinC=17
    /data/weather/tempMinF=63
    /data/weather/windspeedMiles=13
    /data/weather/windspeedKmph=21
    /data/weather/winddirection=N
    /data/weather/winddir16Point=N
    /data/weather/winddirDegree=360
    /data/weather/weatherCode=116
    /data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon16.png
    /data/weather/weatherDesc=Partly Cloudy 
    /data/weather/precipMM=14.1
```

Comment: So you want us to write the code? Did you try anything?

Comment: It seems challenging with 'sed'. Is your only tool?

Comment: What does this have to do with XML?

Comment: i have converted xml file with xml2 to get the line format as given in file1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the awk line should work for u:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if(NR%2)i=$0;else a[i]=$0;next;}{if($0 in a){print; print a[$0]}else print}' file2 file1
```

**EDIT**

here I see no EXTRA lines. see the test. (maybe your example data format is not same as your real data.).

however I have shown the way, how to do it. you can change the awk oneliner to fit your real data format.

```
kent$  cat f1
/data/weather/date=2011-12-18
/data/weather/tempMaxC=25
/data/weather/tempMaxF=76
/data/weather/tempMinC=14
/data/weather/tempMinF=56
/data/weather/windspeedMiles=15
/data/weather/windspeedKmph=24
/data/weather/winddirection=NE
/data/weather/winddir16Point=NE
/data/weather/winddirDegree=39
/data/weather/weatherCode=112
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http:/someurl
/data/weather/weatherDesc= Cloudy 
/data/weather/precipMM=0.0
/data/weather
/data/weather/date=2011-12-19
/data/weather/tempMaxC=29
/data/weather/tempMaxF=84
/data/weather/tempMinC=17
/data/weather/tempMinF=63
/data/weather/windspeedMiles=13
/data/weather/windspeedKmph=21
/data/weather/winddirection=N
/data/weather/winddir16Point=N
/data/weather/winddirDegree=360
/data/weather/weatherCode=116
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http://someurl
/data/weather/weatherDesc=Partly Cloudy 
/data/weather/precipMM=14.1

kent$  cat f2
/data/weather/weatherCode=111
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon1.png
/data/weather/weatherCode=112
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon2.png
/data/weather/weatherCode=113
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon3.png
/data/weather/weatherCode=116
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon16.png


kent$  awk 'FNR==NR{if(NR%2)i=$0;else a[i]=$0;next;}{if($0 in a){print; print a[$0]}else print}' f2 f1
/data/weather/date=2011-12-18
/data/weather/tempMaxC=25
/data/weather/tempMaxF=76
/data/weather/tempMinC=14
/data/weather/tempMinF=56
/data/weather/windspeedMiles=15
/data/weather/windspeedKmph=24
/data/weather/winddirection=NE
/data/weather/winddir16Point=NE
/data/weather/winddirDegree=39
/data/weather/weatherCode=112
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon2.png
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http:/someurl
/data/weather/weatherDesc= Cloudy 
/data/weather/precipMM=0.0
/data/weather
/data/weather/date=2011-12-19
/data/weather/tempMaxC=29
/data/weather/tempMaxF=84
/data/weather/tempMinC=17
/data/weather/tempMinF=63
/data/weather/windspeedMiles=13
/data/weather/windspeedKmph=21
/data/weather/winddirection=N
/data/weather/winddir16Point=N
/data/weather/winddirDegree=360
/data/weather/weatherCode=116
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=images/icon16.png
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http://someurl
/data/weather/weatherDesc=Partly Cloudy 
/data/weather/precipMM=14.1
```

**EDIT2**

without ....sameurl...

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{if(NR%2)i=$0;else a[i]=$0;next;}{if($0 in a){print; print a[$0]}else if ($0!~/someurl/) print}' f2 f1
```

Comment: it added new line in file 1 from file2  but old one is still there?

Comment: add `> tmp.txt` at the end of the command, you will have a file. if you want to replace file1, add `> tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file1` at the end of the commandline

Comment: already did, but tmp.txt contains extra line, old one from file1 and new line from file2?/data/weather/weatherCode=116
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=icon3
/data/weather/weatherIconUrl=http://someurl

Comment: @user1080711 see Edit in the answer.

Comment: I got the same output, but there are two lines in the example you give(in my as well) ....images/icon16.png and under ....http://someurl(which i dont need,hence extra). Should i use another command to remove that line(....http://someurl)?

Comment: THANKS EDIT2 did the job. p.s. so what im doing is editing file1.xml file after converting it with xml2 tool to format as in file1 example. Thank u again.all the best

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'N;s|\(.*\)\n\([^=]*\)\(.*\)|\\!\1!,\\!\2!s!http.*!\3!|' file2 | sed -i -f - file1
```

Explanation:

Generate sed commands from file2 to edit file1.

N.B. I presume in file2 the `-`'s mean the same pattern as above until the last pattern for  code `120` (no empty lines).